# Struggling with referencing a variable (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, function, variables, view

*Background:*
I'm trying to animate a wave using [BAFluidView](https://antiguab.github.io/bafluidview/). My goal is pretty simple: start the animation when a button is tapped, stop it when it is tapped again. The pod (linked above) provides all of the code to manage this.

Let it be known, I'm new to this. Help me learn, please!

---

### My struggle:

I need to create a view for this wave. I put it into a function called "WaveContainer." Here's what that looks like:

```
func WaveAnimation() {

        let wave = BAFluidView(frame: self.view.frame, startElevation: 0.02)!

        wave.maxAmplitude = 10
        wave.minAmplitude = 8
        wave.fillDuration = 50
        wave.fill(to: 0.95)
        wave.fillAutoReverse = false
        wave.fillColor = UIColor.blue

        waveView.addSubview(wave)

    }
```

I then called this in the `ViewDidAppear` function. Of course, it works! I can see the wave, and it's waving. Nice.

Of course, I can't call the `wave` constant anywhere else, though! ***If I want to stop / start the wave on a button press, for example?***

If I try to move the `wave` constant out of this function into `ViewDidLoad` or `ViewDidAppear`, I can't access the `...self.view.frame`, and the wave won't show up on the screen.

### My asks:

1. How should I structure this code so that I can reference the `wave` constant from several different functions?
2. How should I reference the `view` for the `wave` constant when I'm not within ViewDidLoad or some other view-based function?

**Thank you SO MUCH for your help!**

---

#### My Code:

```
import UIKit
import BAFluidView

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // OUTLETS: 

    @IBOutlet weak var waveView: UIView!



    // ACTIONS: 

    @IBAction func WaveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
       // If the user taps this button and the waveHasStarted variable is equal to false, flip it to true.
       if waveHasStarted == false {
            print("Start the wave with a press.")
            startWave = true
            waveHasStarted = true
            waveHasBeenStopped = false
        } else {
            print("Stop the wave with a press.")
            startWave = false
            waveHasStarted = false
            waveHasBeenStopped = true
        }

    }


    // VARIABLES:

    var waveHasStarted = false
    var startWave = false
    var waveHasBeenStopped = true



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {}



    // FUNCTIONS:

    func WaveAnimation() {

        let wave = BAFluidView(frame: self.view.frame, startElevation: 0.02)!

        wave.maxAmplitude = 10
        wave.minAmplitude = 8
        wave.fillDuration = 50
        wave.fill(to: 0.95)
        wave.fillAutoReverse = false
        wave.fillColor = UIColor.blue


        // If the variable above has been flipped to "true," start the animation...
        if startWave == true {
            print("Start that wave animation")
            wave.startAnimation()
        } else {
            // If not, stop it or do nothing.
            print("Stop that wave animation")
            wave.stopAnimation()
            wave.keepStationary()
        }

        waveView.addSubview(wave)

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lazy` initialization and get the `class` level access,

```
lazy var fluidView: BAFluidView = {
       let wave = BAFluidView(frame: self.view.frame, startElevation: 0.02)!
       wave.maxAmplitude = 10
       wave.minAmplitude = 8
       wave.fillDuration = 50
       wave.fill(to: 0.95)
       wave.fillAutoReverse = false
       wave.fillColor = UIColor.blue
       return wave
}()
```

Now you can `add`, `start` and `stop` the animation anywhere as,

```
waveView.addSubview(fluidView)
fluidView.startAnimation()
fluidView.stopAnimation()
```